# Different encryption in Crypto.js and .NET Cryptography using AES

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a message from client and decrypt it on the server. I put the AES key and iv in users cookies.

The problem is that the encrypted string from Crypto.js is `G0eNQap/h6u+7566MTOH3w==`, and the encrypted string from .NET is `F7RemlJeNBhcaZ/FjCK4xw==`. **It has the same length, but not the same value.**

I gues I am doing something wrong with encoding. **Could you point out the mistake?** Thanks in advance.

Crypto.js

```
var communicationKey = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(getCookie("SessionKey"));
    var communicationIV = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(getCookie("IV"));

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", communicationKey, {
        iv: communicationIV,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB
    });

console.log("Result: " + CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext));
```

.NET:

```
string key = context.Cookies["SessionKey"].Value;
newUser.UserKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);

string iv = context.Cookies["IV"].Value;
newUser.InitializationVector = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);

byte[] encryptedMessage = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes("Message", source.UserKey, source.InitializationVector);
```

Comment: What is `newUser` and what is source code of `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes` you're using? It looks like you're using some wrapper over `AesManaged` implementation of AES in .NET - so problem might be there.

Comment: newUser is just a model, having `byte[]` fields. And the `EncryptToBytes_Aes`is the exact implementation from the bottom of the page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: I hope you know that cookies aren't secure. The whole communication has to be done over TLS, otherwise somebody can simply use the key in the cookie to decrypt the contents. This is just a simple obfuscation if you don't use transport layer security. But if you do use it, this becomes obsolete as this doesn't add any better security.

Comment: Yes, I realised that. But the application won't reach the 'real world', it's more of a personal learning project. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your js code you are using `CryptoJS.mode.CFB`.

If your `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes` is exact copy of MSDN sample - then it uses `CBC` AES encryption mode (it is default for AESManaged).

So you have to change either js or C# code for both of them use the same encryption mode.

Comment: Uahh, I totaly missed that. Thanks a lot!